# SQL Query help regarding filtering data

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I wish to generate a list of selected column  from table postion order by PositionDateTime(ie date ). but in that descending order wish to accept only date from particular year.

below sql query does shows data in descending order with reference to date .but i want to execute a sql query that filter out date ie not from current year (ie 2017 for now). eg i dont want to include date  like 2018 and 2005 from below table. how can i execute such query.

```
SELECT Lat, Lng, PositionDateTime FROM Position ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC Limit 30 ;
```

current table result

```
Lat     | Lng     | PositionDateTime    |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
| 47.1168 | 8.19226 | 2018-12-11 13:19:17 |
| 47.0996 | 7.77753 | 2018-12-11 12:55:29 |
| 47.0622 | 7.45892 | 2017-12-11 12:49:14 |
| 46.8484 | 7.33423 | 2017-12-11 12:48:10 |
| 47.2489 | 7.57043 | 2017-12-11 12:29:03 |
| 47.2899 | 8.25708 | 2017-12-11 11:37:41 |
|  47.409 | 7.77917 | 2017-12-11 10:57:42 |
| 47.3941 | 8.68005 | 2017-12-11 10:41:24 |
|       0 |       0 | 2017-12-11 10:39:12 |
|       0 |       0 | 2017-11-23 15:22:25 |
|       0 |       0 | 2017-11-23 12:32:58 |
|       0 |       0 | 2017-11-23 10:24:10 |
|       0 |       0 | 2017-11-20 09:29:36 |
|       0 |       0 | 2017-11-20 09:25:35 |
|       0 |       0 | 2017-11-20 09:25:18 |
| 47.5031 | 8.69181 | 2017-11-15 16:25:08 |
| 47.4799 | 8.48702 | 2005-11-15 16:24:41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `YEAR(PositionDateTime)` in the where clause, you can filter the results by the year:

```
SELECT Lat, Lng, PositionDateTime FROM Position 
WHERE YEAR(PositionDateTime) IN (2015,2017) #Enter the years you want here.
ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC Limit 30 ;
```

Or to show only results for the current year just, try this:

```
SELECT Lat, Lng, PositionDateTime FROM Position 
WHERE YEAR(PositionDateTime) = YEAR(NOW()) 
ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC Limit 30 ;
```

To show only results for the current year and a particular month, try this:

```
SELECT Lat, Lng, PositionDateTime FROM Position 
WHERE YEAR(PositionDateTime) = YEAR(NOW()) 
AND MONTH(PositionDateTime) = 6 # 6 = June, you can adjust this.
ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC Limit 30 ;
```

Comment: actually i want the below sql query to give all details from only current year. so is there any code that will give current year.

Comment: @tomtom I edited my answer there. YEAR(PositionDateTime) = YEAR(NOW())  will work.

Comment: can i add year and month as well

Comment: @tomtom - See updated answer again. You can use MONTH() to filter for specific months, where 1 = January and 12 = December.

Comment: hello leopard thank you. in case in sql statment if i dont want to accept value in query where value is zero and null. how should i add in where condition .